Failed to start LSB while starting WireGuard server
Summarize the problem
Hi, I have an Ubuntu Server 22.04 and I was running on it a WireGuard server. Recently (I don't know exactly when) WireGuard stopped working and it's probably because of changes I did to the server.
Provide details and any research
Most recent chagnes include:

installing qemu-kvm,
trying to configure bridged interface for the VMs with NetworkManager and then NetPlan which ultimately failed probably because I have bind9 running on docker as DNS server and to create it I had to disable resloved (but this was some time ago and didn't disturb the WireGuard)
disabling NetworkManager and using Netplan instead

Log of starting server:
Starting WireGuard via wg-guick(8) for wg0...
[OK] Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Control pmcd (the collection daemon for PCP).
See 'systemctl status pmcd.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Control pmie (performance inference engine for PCP).
See 'systemctl status pmie.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Control pmlogger the performance metrics logger for PCP).
See 'systemctl status pmlogger.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Control pmproxy (the pmcd proxy daemon for PCP).
See 'systemctl status pmproxy.service' for details.
[OK] Finished Permint User Sessions.
[FAILED] Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
See 'systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.service' for details.

Basically all those systemctl status commands return info that there is no /usr/share/pcp/lib/rc-proc.sh
× pmie.service - LSB: Control pmie (performance inference engine for PCP)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/pmie; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-05-04 20:27:01 CEST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 966 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/pmie start (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 6ms

May 04 20:27:01 hagrid systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Control pmie (performance inference engine for PCP)...
May 04 20:27:01 hagrid pmie[966]: /etc/init.d/pmie: 43: .: cannot open /usr/share/pcp/lib/rc-proc.sh: No such file
May 04 20:27:01 hagrid systemd[1]: pmie.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
May 04 20:27:01 hagrid systemd[1]: pmie.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 20:27:01 hagrid systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Control pmie (performance inference engine for PCP).

And wireguard returns:
× wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-05-04 20:52:39 CEST; 36s ago
       Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
             man:wg(8)
             https://www.wireguard.com/
             https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
    Process: 1010 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg0 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1010 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 17ms

May 04 20:52:39 hagrid systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
May 04 20:52:39 hagrid wg-quick[1010]: wg-quick: `wg0' already exists
May 04 20:52:39 hagrid systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 04 20:52:39 hagrid systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 04 20:52:39 hagrid systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.

Describe what you’ve tried
I've searched those errors online and found here that I can run wg-quick down wg0 and restart the wg-quick service and it worked, but when I reboot my server this issue is still there and I don't think that running those commands as a cronjob is a good idea. I couldn't find anything online about the missing rc-proc.sh file though.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.
Edit 1
Those issues are probably not related and it just was some bad luck, that those logs appeared together and looked as they were related.
I've managed to resolve the issue with WireGuard, but I'm not sure what the initial problem was.
My initial iptable rules from WireGuard config:
PostUp = iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE

My new iptable rules in WireGuard config:
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg1 out on enp2s0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg1 out on enp2s0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERAD

I had to create new WireGuard interface with new name wg1 instead of wg0 and I changed the port. The rest of the config remained the same.
I hope it helps someone.
Btw if someone knows what LSB is and how to resolve the issue I would appreciate it.

You are asking about / relating two seemingly-unrelated problems here. No idea what LSB is. The wireguard one probably has something to do with your netplan configuration (like having stuff about the wireguard for some reason). You should probably add it to your post anyway.

Thank you for replying, it now makes more sense to me if those are not related. I also have no idea what LSB is, but I think that I managed to resolve the issue with wireguard and I'll add an edit to the post.
